# Where does the TestFlight desktop app get its code signing identities from?

Tags: code-signing, testflight, code-signing-certificate

When you finish archiving your app and you're ready to publish it onto TestFlight, the TestFlight 'CoPilot' Desktop App presents you this screen:

[image: screenie]

Where it says 'Identity', where on earth does it get that list?

Right now, it contains a lot of outdated identities that look very similar to the most updated ones. This is very confusing and I would like to remove them all.

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer to this?

Comment: Nope not yet. Still waiting for answers from the SO community!

Answer (score 0):

I found it! Both Xcode and TestFlight look in the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` directory.

You can now remove all of the `.mobileprovision` files there and start with a blank slate, if you want.